# Combining property shorthand and rest: { type, which, selected: { ...selected, ...hovered } } : what's happening here?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

EDIT: To everyone who said I needed to provide context: therein lay the answer. Two of the variables below -- `type` and `which` -- come from sources external to this expression and everything in the object created by spreading is assigned to selected. I was thinking that somehow type and which were receiving their values from the object created by spreading as well. Not the case!

I'm modifying code of a departed lead developer and have encountered a formulation which I don't understand.

`{ type, which, selected: { ...selected, ...hovered } }`

from this bit of code

```
export const renderSelector = createSelector(
  selectedTypeSelector,
  selectedSelector,
  hoveredSelector,
  (type, selected, hovered) => memoize(
    which => loadRender({ type, which, selected: { ...selected, ...hovered } }),
  ),
);
```

I've studied ES6 features fairly closely and don't remember having seen this.  I fully get the spreading on the right hand side, but I'm unclear what's happening on the left hand side.  That is: what does `type, which, selected:` do exactly?  I asked around and it was explained to me that the field names on the left of the `:` above capture matching fields in the object created by `{ ...selected, ...hovered }` and that the non-matching fields are put together in a `rest` array if there is a non-matching field name on the left.  Can someone point me to a link that describes this?   Thanks!

Comment: What context is this line in? It looks like it just constructs an object with a `type` property and a `which` property, each in [short-hand notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Property_definitions), and another `selected` property. Nothing special.

Comment: @Xufox is on point - without context we can only give you information that is likely fairly useless. For example `type` will define a new key on the object which is named `type` and would have the value of whatever is contained in the `type` variable. This is a correct explanation but likely not useful to you.

Comment: you can not have two target object with rest parameters, if on lhs.

Comment: Make an object with `type` and `wich` properties that have values of `type` and `wich` values (these are parameters in scope), more info [here](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/es6%20%26%20beyond/ch2.md#concise-properties). The new object has a `selected` property that is an object that has all the `selected` variable keys and is extended or overwritten by `hovered`

Comment: Thanks all, I've tried to add context above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression

```
{ type, which, selected: { ...selected, ...hovered } }
```

is almost<sup>1</sup> equivalent to

```
{
    "type": type,
    "which": which,
    "selected": Object.assign({}, selected, hovered)
}
```

where `type`, `which`, `selected`, and `hovered` are local variables. In other words, `"type"` and `"which"` are specified using the [property shorthand](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015), and `"selected"` is specified explicitly as a shallow merge of `selected` and `hovered`.

---

<sup>1</sup> I say "almost" because `Object.assign` triggers property setters, and `...` object spread syntax does not.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like

```
{ type, which, selected: { ...selected, ...hovered } }
```

some variables are combined to a single object, as

- `type`
- `which`
- a new object `selected` with the properties of

  - `selected`, which contains an object
  - `hovered`, which contains an object, too

with [short hand properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) and [spread syntax `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) for objects.

Answer (score 2):

You create a new object using `type`, `wich`, `selected` and `hovered`

```js
const type = 'value of type';
const which = 'value of which';
const selected = {propOfSelected:'value1',sharedProp:'value1'};
const hovered = {sharedProp:'value2',newProp:'value of new prop'};
console.log({ type, which, selected: { ...selected, ...hovered } })
```

More info about this can be found [here](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/es6%20%26%20beyond/ch2.md#you-dont-know-js-es6--beyond)